# Convert MKCoordinateRegion to MKMapRect

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkcoordinateregion, mkmaprect

I have a square MKMapView in my app, and I wish to set a center point and the exact height/width of the view in meters.

Creating an MKCoordinateRegion and setting the map to it (as in this code...

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center_coord, 1000.0, 1000.0);
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

..) doesn't work properly because using regions here just means that at least that region is displayed, typically more than the region is.

I'm planning on using [setVisibleMapRect:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205) method instead, as I believe this will zoom to the actual [MKMapRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MKMapSize) passed.

**So, is there a simple way to convert between an MKcoordinateRegion and an MKMapRect? Perhaps getting the top-left and bottom-right coordinates of the region, and using them to the make the MKMapRect?**

I couldn't see anything handy in the [Map Kit Functions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MKMapPointMake).

*(Using iOS 5, Xcode 4.2)*

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To add another implementation to the pile:

```
- (MKMapRect)MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region
{
    MKMapPoint a = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
        region.center.latitude + region.span.latitudeDelta / 2, 
        region.center.longitude - region.span.longitudeDelta / 2));
    MKMapPoint b = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
        region.center.latitude - region.span.latitudeDelta / 2, 
        region.center.longitude + region.span.longitudeDelta / 2));
    return MKMapRectMake(MIN(a.x,b.x), MIN(a.y,b.y), ABS(a.x-b.x), ABS(a.y-b.y));
}
```

NB: There are many ways to convert between `MKMapRect` and `MKCoordinateRegion`. This one certainly is *not* the exact inverse of `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance()`, but approximates it fairly well. So, be careful converting back and forth, because information can be lost.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Using a map rect instead of a region is a great way to do an offset, because `setVisibleMapRect` has an option for edge insets.

Comment: This produces wrong result, the resulting rect is flipped sideways. I used @Wan Liqun answer below, it worked perfectly!

Comment: As @PavelGurov mentioned, this produces incorrect result? I think the last line should be, in Swift, `return MKMapRectMake(a.x, a.y, abs(a.x-b.x), abs(a.y-b.y)`.

Comment: @PavelGurov is right, despite this working, on some situations, for instance near the max./min. longitude it produces wrong results.

Answer (score 48):

This is a Swift version to Leo & Barnhart solution

```
func MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region:MKCoordinateRegion) -> MKMapRect {
    let topLeft = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: region.center.latitude + (region.span.latitudeDelta/2), longitude: region.center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta/2))
    let bottomRight = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: region.center.latitude - (region.span.latitudeDelta/2), longitude: region.center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta/2))

    let a = MKMapPoint(topLeft)
    let b = MKMapPoint(bottomRight)
    
    return MKMapRect(origin: MKMapPoint(x:min(a.x,b.x), y:min(a.y,b.y)), size: MKMapSize(width: abs(a.x-b.x), height: abs(a.y-b.y)))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Comment: For Swift 4.2 change this: let a = MKMapPoint(topLeft)
let b = MKMapPoint(bottomRight)

Answer (score 13):

Use MKMapPointForCoordinate to convert the 2 point of the region (top/left and bottom/right), then create the MKMapRect using the 2 MKMapPoints

```
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateOrigin = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateMax = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude + cellSize, longitude + cellSize);

        MKMapPoint upperLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinateOrigin);
        MKMapPoint lowerRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinateMax);

        MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake(upperLeft.x,
                                          upperLeft.y,
                                          lowerRight.x - upperLeft.x,
                                          lowerRight.y - upperLeft.y);
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use method to convert `MKCoordinateRegion` to `CGRect`

```
- (CGRect)convertRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region toRectToView:(UIView *)view
```

and use `- (MKMapRect)mapRectForRect:(CGRect)rect`

or use `MKMapPointForCoordinate` method  to first convert coordinates to `MKPoint` and use that to form `MKMapRect` to eventually use `setVisibleMapRect:animated:`

Comment: Could you add the class that the functions you mentioned belong to? and possibly a full example on how to actually do the conversion

Comment: @Daniel it was deprecated in iOS7, it's probably why you don't find the method. You can find it in the overlay class.

Answer (score 9):

@Bogdan

I think it should be:

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoordinate =
CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinateRegion.center.latitude
                           + (coordinateRegion.span.latitudeDelta/2.0),
                           coordinateRegion.center.longitude
                           - (coordinateRegion.span.longitudeDelta/2.0));

MKMapPoint topLeftMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(topLeftCoordinate);

CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoordinate =
CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinateRegion.center.latitude
                           - (coordinateRegion.span.latitudeDelta/2.0),
                           coordinateRegion.center.longitude
                           + (coordinateRegion.span.longitudeDelta/2.0));

MKMapPoint bottomRightMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(bottomRightCoordinate);

MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake(topLeftMapPoint.x,
                                  topLeftMapPoint.y,
                                  fabs(bottomRightMapPoint.x-topLeftMapPoint.x),
                                  fabs(bottomRightMapPoint.y-topLeftMapPoint.y));
```

According to [apple api reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKMapRect), MKCoordinateRegion.center represents the center point of the region;
and MKCoordinateSpan.latitudeDelta represents the amount of north-to-south distance (measured in degrees) to display on the map; MKCoordinateSpan.longitudeDelta represents amount of east-to-west distance (measured in degrees) to display for the map region.

Comment: This produces the expected result, not the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

Still have to be a bit more careful about crossing the meridian (as well as wrapping around the poles) otherwise MKMapPointForCoordinate returns -1, -1:

```
public func MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region:MKCoordinateRegion) -> MKMapRect {
var topLeft = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
    latitude: min(region.center.latitude + (region.span.latitudeDelta/2.0), 90),
    longitude: region.center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta/2.0)
)

if topLeft.longitude < -180 {
    // We wrapped around the meridian
    topLeft.longitude += 360
}

var bottomRight = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
    latitude: max(region.center.latitude - (region.span.latitudeDelta/2.0), -90),
    longitude: region.center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta/2.0)
)

    if bottomRight.longitude > 180 {
        // We wrapped around the medridian
        bottomRight.longitude -= 360
    }

    let topLeftMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(topLeft)
    let bottomRightMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(bottomRight)

    var width = bottomRightMapPoint.x - topLeftMapPoint.x
    if width < 0.0 {
        // Rect crosses meridian
        width += MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 180.0)).x
    }
    let height = bottomRightMapPoint.y - topLeftMapPoint.y
    let size = MKMapSize(width: width, height: height)

    return MKMapRect(origin: topLeftMapPoint, size: size)
}
```

Some test case code (using Nimble):

```
func testMKMapRectForCoordinateRegion() {
    let northWesternRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.0, -90.0), MKCoordinateSpanMake(20.0, 20.0))
    let northWesternMapRect = MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region: northWesternRegion)
    let convertedNWRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(northWesternMapRect)
    expect(self.equivalentRegions(northWesternRegion, convertedNWRegion)).to(beTrue())

    let northEasternRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.0, 90.0), MKCoordinateSpanMake(20.0, 20.0))
    let northEasternMapRect = MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region: northEasternRegion)
    let convertedNERegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(northEasternMapRect)
    expect(self.equivalentRegions(northEasternRegion, convertedNERegion)).to(beTrue())

    let southWesternRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-45.0, -90.0), MKCoordinateSpanMake(20.0, 20.0))
    let southWesternMapRect = MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region: southWesternRegion)
    let convertedSWRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(southWesternMapRect)
    expect(self.equivalentRegions(southWesternRegion, convertedSWRegion)).to(beTrue())

    let southEasternRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-45.0, 90.0), MKCoordinateSpanMake(20.0, 20.0))
    let southEasternMapRect = MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region: southEasternRegion)
    let convertedSERegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(southEasternMapRect)
    expect(self.equivalentRegions(southEasternRegion, convertedSERegion)).to(beTrue())

    let meridianSpanEastRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.0, 170.0), MKCoordinateSpanMake(20.0, 20.0))
    let meridianSpanEastMapRect = MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region: meridianSpanEastRegion)
    let convertedMeridianSpanEastRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(meridianSpanEastMapRect)
    expect(self.equivalentRegions(meridianSpanEastRegion, convertedMeridianSpanEastRegion)).to(beTrue())

    let meridianSpanWestRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.0, -170.0), MKCoordinateSpanMake(20.0, 20.0))
    let meridianSpanWestMapRect = MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region: meridianSpanWestRegion)
    let convertedMeridianSpanWestRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(meridianSpanWestMapRect)
    expect(self.equivalentRegions(meridianSpanWestRegion, convertedMeridianSpanWestRegion)).to(beTrue())
}

fileprivate func equivalentRegions(_ regionA: MKCoordinateRegion, _ regionB: MKCoordinateRegion) -> Bool {
    // Allow a small delta between values
    let deltaAllowed: Double = 1.0

    return (fabs(regionA.center.latitude - regionB.center.latitude) < deltaAllowed) &&
            (fabs(regionA.center.longitude - regionB.center.longitude) < deltaAllowed) &&
            (fabs(regionA.span.latitudeDelta - regionB.span.latitudeDelta) < deltaAllowed) &&
            (fabs(regionA.span.longitudeDelta - regionB.span.longitudeDelta) < deltaAllowed)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@David's answer, in Swift 3

```
func mapRect(region: MKCoordinateRegion) -> MKMapRect {
  let topLeft = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
    latitude: region.center.latitude + (region.span.latitudeDelta/2.0),
    longitude: region.center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta/2.0)
  )

  let bottomRight = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
    latitude: region.center.latitude - (region.span.latitudeDelta/2.0),
    longitude: region.center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta/2.0)
  )

  let topLeftMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(topLeft)
  let bottomRightMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(bottomRight)

  let origin = MKMapPoint(x: topLeftMapPoint.x,
                          y: topLeftMapPoint.y)
  let size = MKMapSize(width: fabs(bottomRightMapPoint.x - topLeftMapPoint.x),
                       height: fabs(bottomRightMapPoint.y - topLeftMapPoint.y))

  return MKMapRect(origin: origin, size: size)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer @David gave (and consequently the Swift 3 version by @onmyway133) has a significant error whenever the region crosses over the anti-meridian from the Eastern Hemisphere (longitude 0 degrees to 180 degrees) to the Western Hemisphere (longitude -180 degrees to 0 degrees). The width of the MKMapRect will be bigger than it should be (usually *much* bigger).

Here is the fix (for the Swift 3 code):

```
let topLeftMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(topLeft)
let bottomRightMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(bottomRight)
var width = bottomRightMapPoint.x - topLeftMapPoint.x
if width < 0.0 {
    // Rect crosses from the Eastern Hemisphere to the Western Hemisphere
    width += MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 180.0)).x
}
let height = bottomRightMapPoint.y - topLeftMapPoint.y
let size = MKMapSize(width: width, height: height)
return MKMapRect(origin: topLeftMapPoint, size: size)
```

Taking an MKCoordinateRegion, converting it into an MKMapRect with the code above, and then turning it back into an MKCoordinateRegion using MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect() gives me very good agreement between the input region and the output region everywhere on the map.

Comment: @GilroyKilroy quite correctly clips latitude at [-90, 90]. A coordinate region that spans a pole would look like a bowtie as you look down on the polar region, and that would translate into two disjoint MKMapRect areas.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5.1:

```
func mapRectForCoordinateRegion(_ region: MKCoordinateRegion) -> MKMapRect {
   let topLeftCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(region.center.latitude + (region.span.latitudeDelta / 2.0), region.center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0))
   let topLeftMapPoint = MKMapPoint(topLeftCoordinate)
   let bottomRightCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(region.center.latitude - (region.span.latitudeDelta / 2.0), region.center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0))
   let bottomRightMapPoint = MKMapPoint(bottomRightCoordinate)
   return MKMapRect(x: topLeftMapPoint.x, y: topLeftMapPoint.y, width: fabs(bottomRightMapPoint.x - topLeftMapPoint.x), height: fabs(bottomRightMapPoint.y - topLeftMapPoint.y))
```

}

Answer (score 0):

And because extensions rule, here is an extension for swift:

```swift
extension MKCoordinateRegion {
    public var rect : MKMapRect {
        let topLeft = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.center.latitude + (self.span.latitudeDelta/2), longitude: self.center.longitude - (self.span.longitudeDelta/2))
        let bottomRight = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.center.latitude - (self.span.latitudeDelta/2), longitude: self.center.longitude + (self.span.longitudeDelta/2))

        let a = MKMapPoint(topLeft)
        let b = MKMapPoint(bottomRight)
        
        return MKMapRect(origin: MKMapPoint(x:min(a.x,b.x), y:min(a.y,b.y)), size: MKMapSize(width: abs(a.x-b.x), height: abs(a.y-b.y)))
    }
}
```

Which allows for: `region.rect` to just work :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the built in function `MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect`

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect);
```

Comment: this is the inverse of the conversion asked for, but good to know I guess

Comment: Apple has not given the direct functions because that inappropriate to convert region to rect. You should not be doing this with your app.