# What's the difference between MKMapRect and MKCoordinateRegion

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

They both specify a map center and how big the box is.

So why use both?

Some function in `MKMapview` use one and some use the other

- `(MKCoordinateRegion)regionThatFits:(MKCoordinateRegion)region`
- `(MKMapRect)mapRectThatFits:(MKMapRect)mapRect
  edgePadding:(UIEdgeInsets)insets`

What's their difference?

More importantly, which one we should use to set the region we see?

There is no `regionThatFits:edgePadding:` by the way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `MKCoordinateRegion` is defined using degrees coordinate of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D` which represents the latitude and longitude of a point on the surface of the globe.

`MKMapRect` represents an actual flat rectangle defined with view coordinate (x, y) on your map view.

You can use functions to do conversions for you like [MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect)

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html

And to answer your final question, you would use `MKCoordinateRegion` which will define what region of the globe's surface you want to see and by definition it will set your zoom level.

Comment: What's that x and y contain? Latitude Longitude?

Comment: No they are the map view x-axis and y-axis coordinate. `MKMapRect` and `CGRect` are basically the same. Except that you have to use `MKMapRect` if you want to do operations using the Map Kit Functions

Comment: MKMapKit uses the Mercator map projection. The X and Y values correspond to your position on this projection. Apple has a good write-up on it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html

Comment: Apple doesn't currently include `MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion` functionality; here's [a link to a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270268/convert-mkcoordinateregion-to-mkmaprect) with a couple of solutions.