# MKMapView center coordinates inside specific frame

Tags: ios, mapkit

Is there a way to center mapView on specific coordinates in specific mapView's frame?

Let me illustrate:

I have a centered pin:

[image]

At some point of time popup view may appear and I need to center my pin in visible `mapView` rect:

[image]

Moreover I have to do this during popup appearing animating (this is another issue since `popup.frame` is no KVO compliant)

**What I have:**

I've implemented fast-&-dirty solution  by centering mapView on fake location. 
Simply I copied fake coordinates from original and replaced `latitude`, this lets original pin to be on top of popup.

But this approach not really elegant and not accurate.

**Important:** 
I can't change mapView's frame simple because popup has indents through which map is visible.

Comment: This answer helped me to resolve this question :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15421512/3379376