# User Current Location on specific position on MAP

Tags: ios, swift3, mkmapview, core-location

- **MKMapView**
- **CoreLocation**
- **Swift3.0**

I have a requirement like this:

Creating an application in which I am getting `Lat and Long` for various location from webservice . Ploting these locations on map with Custom `AnnotationView` . Apart from this, I'm showing `User Current Location with Custom Image`.

Here everything working `fine`.

Now, when user moves then User Current Location Pin changes its position so there is an important requirement for this, I need to make this Current Location position in such a way that it stick in the bottom of map (`just 100 pixel`) above from bottom.

I did Some RND and find out few useful links:

- [Centering MKMapView on spot N-pixels below pin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15421106/3400991)
- [How can I center my mapview so that the selected pin is not in the middle of the map but in 1/3 of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37288138/3400991)
- [set current location icon lower side in MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509112/set-current-location-icon-lower-side-in-mkmapview)

But this not working anymore. 
Kindly suggest how can I set user Current Location pin in `iOS` map in such a way that it always at the bottom of Map (100 pixel above from Bottom)

Required Pin position:
[image]

Currently it is showing in other position.

**Note - **Dont want Google Map for such functionality**.

Comment: I do not really understand your question, do you want to 1.have the pin to be visually at that location even when the user pans around or 2.pin the map to that spot when the user does an action or 3.have the map shift that the pin is at the location the screen? You might want to describe you problem clearer or add some images to show the result you want

Comment: @Ben Ong i want to  have the pin to be visually at that location even when the user pans around

Comment: @BenOng  i updated question with screenshot , i need same pin position whenever user zoom and first time screen shows

Comment: @vadian kindly share your suggestion on this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/41057877/3400991

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the trick to use to position the map in such a way that UserLocation pin gets adjusted automatically :

```
func setUserLocationOnLowerPositiononMap(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        region.center = coordinate
        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        //self.map.moveCenterByOffSet(offSet: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -130), coordinate: coordinate)
        self.map.moveCenterByOffSet(offSet: CGPoint(x: 0, y: SCREEN_HEIGHT - SCREEN_HEIGHT * 4/3 + 0 ), coordinate: coordinate)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have been using something like this `mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.Follow, animated: true)` then user location will be always displayed in the center of the map, zoom/pan will be automatically adjusted whenever user location is updated.

You need to disable the `UserTrackingMode` and then manually adjust the map zoom/pan using `func setVisibleMapRect(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, edgePadding insets: UIEdgeInsets, animated animate: Bool)` each time whenever user location is changed.

I used following code in similar situation

```
let annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(mapView.userLocation.coordinate);
var zoomRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 1, 1);
annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
let pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 1, 1);
zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
mapView.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 50, 160, 50), animated: true)
```

p.s. `edgePadding` is your friend in this case.

Comment: so where i need to use this code , which delegate i mean

Comment: i updated question with screenshot , i need same pin position whenever user zoom and first time screen shows

Comment: I'd go with this answer, you can use these codes in func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) of the CLLocationMangerDelegate - probably your view controller or the superview of your mapView